# redux - how to store and update a key/value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using redux wth reactjs.

I want to store simple key/value pairs but can't get the reducer syntax right.

In this case each key/value pair will hold a connection to an external system.

Is this the right way to do it?  I'm at the beginning with redux so it's a bit of mystery.

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'addConnection':
      return    {
        connections: {
          ...state.connections, {
          action.compositeKey: action.connection
        }
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'addConnection':
      return {
        ...state,
        connections: {
          ...state.connections,
          [action.compositeKey]: action.connection
        }
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

From the docs:

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#correct-approach-copying-all-levels-of-nested-data

Answer (score 8):

You just have a couple mistakes with `{}` instead of `[]` and forgetting to use `Object.assign`.

```
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'addConnection':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        connections: [
           ...state.connections,
           {
             [actions.compositeKey]: action.connection
           }
        ]
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

It might help to see it expressed this way too. It does the same thing but I think it reads a little nicer

```
const reducer = (state = {}, {type, compositeKey, connection}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'addConnection':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        connections: state.connections.concat({
          [compositeKey]: connection
        })
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

Or if you're using [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), something like this

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';

const reducer = (state = Immutable.Map(), {type, compositeKey, connection}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'addConnection':
      return state.set(
        'connections',
        state.get('connections').concat({
          [compositeKey]: connection
        })
      );
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

Comment: When I use the second or third options that you present, it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: action is not defined" on compilation.

Comment: I forgot to assign `type` in the destructuring of `action`. They should be good now :)

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```
const reducer = (state = {}, {type, compositeKey, connection}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'addConnection':
      var newData={};
      newData[compositeKey]=connection;
      return Object.assign({}, state, newData)
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```