# How to store state values as key value pair in redux..?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, store, key-value

Possible duplicates:

- [redux - how to store and update a key/value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404050/redux-how-to-store-and-update-a-key-value-pair)
- [How to assign new key value pair without overwriting top level keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334870/how-to-assign-new-key-value-pair-without-overwriting-top-level-keys)

Above possible duplicates are not satisfy my need.

Below is the **redux reducer** code i used to store as array of objects:

```
case 'ADD_ITEM':
  return {...state, elements:[...state.elements, action.appElements]}
```

where `action.appElements` contains:

```
{id: '9aq05d', width: '100',height: '225'}
```

Stored array of objects will look like:

```
elements: {
  0: {
    id: 9aq05d,
    width: '100',
    height: '225',
  }
  1: {
    id: 8lk65f,
    width: '200',
    height: '787',
  }
}
```

But i need to store the values as **key value pair** as given below:

Where i need **id as key**.

```
elements: {
  9aq05d: {
    id: 9aq05d,
    width: '100',
    height: '225',
  }
  8lk65f: {
    id: 8lk65f,
    width: '200',
    height: '787',
  }
}
```

How to store this kind of key value pair in redux store..?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use object spread instead of array spread.

```
case 'ADD_ITEM':
  return {
          ...state,
          elements: {
            ...state.elements,
            [action.appElements.id]: action.appElements
          }
  }
```

But keep in mind that the order of keys in objects is not guaranteed.